# Morphism that is not a mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have encountered a statement in Lang's Algebra (Revised Third Edition, page 53) concerning morphisms of objects that seems strange to me: "In practice, in this book we shall see that most of our morphisms are actually mappings, or closely related to mappings."

I have always been under the impression that the terms 'mapping' and 'morphism' are synonymous in the context of categories. Perhaps it is just the case that Lang defines the two in a way that they disagree, but I can't find such an instance. Are they in fact different? If so, what is an example of a morphism that is not a mapping?

Comment: It looks like Lang is here using 'mapping' as a synonym for 'function' ... In fact, I see that the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)) article on the term 'map[ping]' in mathematics draws attention to the way in which Lang, specifically, uses the term! Rather than 'mapping' being a synonym for 'function', it is, for him, a more inclusive term, meaning what everybody else means by 'function' - while Lang uses the term 'function' in a more restrictive way (which I, for one, haven't encountered before). That seems nonstandard to me - but who am I to disagree with Lang? :)

Comment: It seems to me that Lang was a man of revolutionary thought that was so revolutionary that he created an abundance of definitions that only he observed. Perhaps we are all still behind the pioneer and his ways without even realizing. I know I am... :)

Comment: I'm less a revolutionary, more someone whose thoughts go round in circles. :)

Comment: Of course, there is always the category Rel, whose objects are sets, and arrows are relations between sets...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any preordered set $X$, one can define a category whose objects are the elements of $X$, such that $\mathrm{Mor}(x,y)$ has one element if $x\leq y$ and is empty otherwise. This defines a category because $x\leq x$ for all $x\in X$, and if $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$ then $x\leq z$.

For another example, any monoid $M$ defines a category with one object, whose set of morphisms is the monoid $M$. The composition law is given by the monoid operation.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still having some trouble wrapping my head around elements of a monoid being able to be seen as morphisms, but I see the point and the difference makes sense now!

Comment: For a concrete example of the monoid example, taking $\mathbb{N}$ as the object (although the object doesn't necessarily have to be $\mathbb{N}$) and the elements of $\mathbb{N}$  as morphisms with multiplication for the composition law is allowed since for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{N}$ (with 1 being the identity morphism), correct?

Comment: Yeah, that works.

Answer (score 6):

One of my favorite "counterexamples" to preconceived notions about categories is matrix algebra:

- The objects are natural numbers
- The arrows are matrices ($\hom(m,n)$ is the collection of $n \times m$ matrices)
- Composition of arrows is the matrix product

Comment: +1, though one can ''identify'' an object $n$ of this category with the vector space $F^{n}$ of dimension $n$, in which case you can think of the matrices as representing linear transformations; more formally, I think there is an equivalence of categories which sends $n$ to $F^{n}$ and a matrix in $hom(n, m)$ to the associated linear map $F^{n} \to F^{m}$. For this reason, I tend to prefer the usual poset example as a category whose morphisms aren't set functions (though maybe there's an analogous nitpick for that example that I'm unaware of).

Comment: @AlexWertheim: I guess with the poset example you mean the example carmichael561 wrote, but with a partial order instead of a preorder. If I'm not mistaken, the poset example could be written as follows: Be $(P,\le)$ the poset. Then the objects are the sets $L_x:=\{a\in P: a\le x\}$, and the morphisms are the functions $f: L_x\to L_y$ which map all elements to themselves. Clearly there's at most one morphism between each pair of objects, and that morphism only exists if $L_x\subseteq L_y$, which is the case if $x\le y$.

Comment: @celtschk: interesting, I was unaware of this reformulation. Thanks for the information! I guess my comment isn't so useful, then. :)

Comment: @Alex: Yep -- and I would counter it more accurately describes actual practice to take vectors from $\hom(1,m)$, and that the morphism induces a linear transformation $\hom(1,m) \to \hom(1,n)$, which is a nice step on the path to introducing generalized elements.

Comment: @Hurkyl could you please recommend a book, which contains an example with $n$ or $m = 0$? More accurately: a book, that contains some information about "empty" matrices and operations with them.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a naturally-occurring example (coming from computability theory) of a category whose morphisms really aren't "maps" in any good sense:

- The **objects** are just the sets of natural numbers.
- A *pre-morphism* from $A$ to $B$ is a Turing machine $\Phi_e$ such that $\Phi_e^A=B$.

We say that two pre-morphisms $\Phi_{e_0}, \Phi_{e_1}: A\rightarrow B$ are **equivalent** (and write $e_0\sim e_1$) if for every $X, n$, $$\Phi_{e_0}^X(n)\cong \Phi_{e_1}^X(n)$$ (where "$P\cong Q$" means "either both $P$ and $Q$ are undefined, or $P$ and $Q$ are both defined and are equal to each other").

- A **morphism** is then an equivalence class of pre-morphisms: $$Hom(A, B)=\{\{e_1: e_1\sim e_0\}: \Phi_{e_0}^A=B\}.$$

Now each object is a set . . . but the morphisms don't act as functions between those sets! (This is the fundamental difference between *many-one reduction* and *Turing reduction*.) Meanwhile, each morphism is a function - specifically, a partial function from $2^\omega$ to $2^\omega$ - but this functional behavior isn't really reflected in what a given morphism does to a given object! So this category doesn't really satisfy the intuition that morphisms are functions between objects.